# Ubuntu Touch apparmor denials when making Http Post/Get requests?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, network-manager, application-development, qml, apparmor

I'm trying my hand at developing a native QML app for Ubuntu Touch, but when it comes to fetching remote content from my server to populate a list view, it fails with an apparmor denial.

Here is my ListModel which I use to populate an UbuntuListView. The ListModel has a function called fetchposts() which iteratively performs an XmlHttpRequest to get a post's comment and list of tags.

```
ListModel {
    id: postsModel

    function fetchposts() {
        postsModel.clear() // empty our list view
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open("GET", server + "/postnum", true)
        http.send(null)
        var postnum = http.responseText
        /* repopulate list view */
        for (var i = 1; i <= postnum; i++) {
            http.open("GET", server + "/p/" + i + ".txt", true)
            http.send(null)
            var postComment = http.responseText
            http.open("GET", server + "/p/" + i + "_werc/tags", true)
            http.send(null)
            var postTags = http.responseText
            postsModel.append({"comment":postComment, "tags":postTags})
        }
   }
}
```

When I call `postsModel.fetchposts()` later though, I get the following errors:

```
QNetworkManagerInterface::QNetworkManagerInterface(QObject*) propsReply "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.1827" (uid=32011 pid=28754 comm="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmlscene Toku") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (uid=0 pid=1592 comm="NetworkManager ")"
QNetworkManagerInterface::QNetworkManagerInterface(QObject*) nmReply "An AppArmor policy prevents this sender from sending this message to this recipient; type="method_call", sender=":1.1827" (uid=32011 pid=28754 comm="/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/qt5/bin/qmlscene Toku") interface="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" member="GetDevices" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.freedesktop.NetworkManager" (uid=0 pid=1592 comm="NetworkManager ")"
"Object path cannot be empty"
```

And here is my apparmor file:

```
{
    "policy_groups": [
         "networking",
         "webview",
         "connectivity",
         "content_exchange",
         "content_exchange_source",
     ],
     "policy_version": 1.3
}
```

Am I making these requests wrong? How do I make an http request without getting an apparmor denial?

If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: I have the same issue, even with the UbuntuComponents WebView example from the dokumentation. Should i file a bug or am i missing something?

Comment: @NeoTheThird seems there's already a bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/qtbase-opensource-src/+bug/1541686). It's been marked fixed, but given you, me, and at least one other guy who commented in June are still affected... I would say it's a bug or at least a lack of good documentation. Not sure if I'm missing something as well.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I did not see that one before. I'm new to launchpad...